# jquery dragging object fast problem

Tags: jquery, draggable, performance

If I drag an object very slow, it does exactly what I want it to do. However, if I do it a bit faster or very fast, it does not work as expected. You can see both results: the expected, while dragging slow and the flawless, when dragging fast. I am just a jquery beginner, if you see any other stupid parts of the JS code, please let me know.

The moving object in the background (while dragging the draggable object) should return to its native position each 20 pixels it is moved away from map holder. It does not do that when moved fast, it does, however, when draggin the trigger slow.

The live example: http://jsbin.com/egeki3

p.s. drag top/bottom directions only

The JS part only (using jQuery UI)

```
    $().ready(function(){
 // map measurments
 var mapWidth = parseInt($('#map').width());
 var mapHeight = parseInt($('#map').height());

 var fragmentH = 20;
 var fragmentW = 20;

 // number of map fragments to use
 var mapBlocksH = Math.ceil(mapHeight/fragmentH)+2;
 var mapBlocksW = Math.ceil(mapWidth/fragmentW)+2;

 // the area size of map fragments displacement
 var mapH  = mapBlocksH*fragmentH;
 var mapW  = mapBlocksW*fragmentW;

 // calculate the maps fragments wrapper position, dimension
 $('#map div.map, div.drag').css({height: mapH, width: mapW, left: (mapWidth-mapW)/2, top: (mapHeight-mapH)/2});

 for(i = 0; i < mapBlocksH*mapBlocksW; i++)
 {
  $('#map div.map').append('<div></div>');
 }

 $('#map div.drag').draggable({
  revert: true,
  revertDuration: 0,
  addClasses: false,
  start : function(event, ui){
   mapOriginalOffset = $('#map div.map').offset();
   //mapOriginalOffset2 = $('#map div.map').offset();
  },
  drag : function(event, ui){
   $('#map div.map').offset({top: mapOriginalOffset.top + (ui.originalPosition.top-ui.position.top)});

   if(Math.abs($('#map div.map').offset().top-$('#map').offset().top) % fragmentH == 0)
   {
    $('#map div.map').offset({top: mapOriginalOffset.top});

    return false;
    //$('#map div.map').offset({top: mapOriginalOffset.top});

    //mapOriginalOffset2.top = $('#map div.drag').offset().top;
   }
  },
  stop : function(event, ui){
  }
 });
```

Comment: Just a side note, `$().ready(function(){` is deprecated, you should use `$(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){` :)

Comment: Thank you. Fixed in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

When you drag an object, the object doesn't take all the position possible, but skip some pixel.

I log the .top position, and the value are 8, 11, 18, 27, so it is rare that the condition

```
Math.abs($('#map div.map').offset().top-$('#map').offset().top) % fragmentH == 0
```

is true.

For your case, it is better to have something like

```
Math.abs($('#map div.map').offset().top-$('#map').offset().top) >= fragmentH
```

It only depends on what you exactly want to do, but do not use modulo with pixel arithmetic & dragging, bad idea !

Comment: I do understand that jquery does not log all the positions when dragging fast. This is exactly the problem I am trying to solve. And Your sollution is no good for me. I need to know EXACT moment when

Math.abs($('#map div.map').offset().top-$('#map').offset().top) % fragmentH == 0

is TRUE.

Comment: Try to explain why you need this exact condition, and we will try to find a solution. We need a context !

Comment: I am making somewhat a Google maps prototype. I need it to diplay some local maps & I need it to run on jQuery. Basically the idea is, when the color boxes area moves away more than 20px (the size of the map fragment) the map display area should return to primary position and only change the background images. It is basically more or less how google maps work (they use absolute positioning appending though)

Comment: So you need to track when the dragging is ending the position of the object, and if it is outside the map fragment, recenter it and change background. Put your piece of code into the stop event, and test the position of the object.